# catalyst deploy for high performance site

Tags: perl, deployment, web-deployment, host, catalyst

I'm going to deploy a [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org) web app, but I am not sure what is the best way to deploy it. I've seen a lot of names come up, such as `nginx`,`Starman`,`fastcgi`, `mod_perl`, `Apache`, `Plack`, however I have not been able to find out which way is the best way to host a `Catalyst` app for high performance. I've found many articles or answers, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651267/what-are-best-practices-for-deploying-a-catalyst-application-to-a-production-ser) or [this](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2011/16), however they all seem to be fairly outdated (the previous examples are from '09 and '11). Does anyone have a strong stance on what is the best way to deploy a `Catalyst` app? I will not need the ability for the servers that are running the `Catalyst` app to server out static content, as that will be served out from a different server.

Answer (score 4):

I use nginx + fastcgi: http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/adventcalendararticles/2008/02-catalyst_and_nginx

Most of my Catalyst web app are divided in 4 parts:

- static => served by nginx only
- admin => gets its own fast_cgi with few children
- API => gets its own fast_cgi with many children
- rest => gets its own fast_cgi with many children

So I have 3 myserver_fastcgi.pl running, each serving a different part of the application. I use Nginx to redirect the traffic to the right server, based on the location isnide the URL, typically:

- /static
- /api
- /admin
- /

Comment: After years of using Catalyst with Apache and mod_perl, I'm completely sold on the combination Julien referred to, and am using it on a current project. Although I have not separated out the admin functions from the rest of the app. That's an interesting tweak.

Comment: what benefits does nginx + fastcgi have over apache + mod_perl?